# fazer diagrama de Sankey com links nos dois sentidos R

Tags: r, diagrama

Eu tenho os seguintes dados que utilizo para fazer o diagrama de Sankey:

```
list(nodes = structure(list(name = c("1.1.1. Formação Florestal", 
"1.1.2. Formação Savanica", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "3.1. Pastagem", NA, NA, NA, "3.2.1. Cultura Anual e Perene", 
NA, "3.3. Mosaico de Agricultura e Pastagem", NA, NA, "4.2. Infraestrutura Urbana", 
"4.5. Outra Área não Vegetada", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "5.1 Rio ou Lago ou Oceano"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -31L)), links = structure(list(
    source = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
    12, 12, 16, 16, 16, 16, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 21, 22, 22, 
    22, 30), target = c(0, 18, 1, 18, 12, 0, 22, 1, 30, 16, 12, 
    18, 0, 22, 1, 30, 12, 16, 1, 18, 1, 18, 22, 30, 12, 0, 1, 
    22, 1, 30, 30), value = c(0.544859347827813, 0.00354385993588971, 
    0.494359662221154, 4.67602736159475, 2.20248911690968, 0.501437742068369, 
    0.00354375594818463, 24.8427814053755, 0.439418727642527, 
    0.0079740332093807, 11.8060486886398, 2.76329829691466, 0.000886029792298199, 
    0.00177186270758855, 3.35504921147758, 0.14263144351167, 
    1.12170804870686, 0.0478454594554582, 0.217079959877658, 
    0.00620223918980076, 1.79754946594068, 9.02868098124075, 
    0.00442981113709027, 0.242743895018645, 0.498770814980772, 
    0.00265782877794886, 0.000885894856554407, 0.379188333632346, 
    0.00265793188317263, 0.00265771537700804, 0.39158027235054
    )), row.names = c(NA, -31L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Meus dados possuem o links e os nodes para criação do diagrama. Alguns links tem auto-referência (de um node para ele mesmo) e referência circular (de um node para outro e então volta para o primeiro). Neste caso de dados eu preciso que o nodes tenham dois sentidos como na Figura 1 abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando fazer o mesmo gráfico utilizando o pacote networkD3, utilizando o seguinte código:

```
sankeyNetwork(Links = landuse$links, Nodes = landuse$nodes, Source = "source",
              Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
              units = "km²", fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 30)
```

Me parece que o pacote não consegue fazer o gráfico com os dados formatados dessa forma. O máximo que consigo fazer retirando os nodes circulares e as auto-referencias é esse resultado apresentado na Figura 2:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O diagrama acima está muito aquém do que desejo. É possível fazer o diagrama como gostaria utilizando este pacote? Existe outro pacote no R que posso fazer o gráfico com nodes nos dois sentidos e que suporte auto-referencia e referencias circulares como na Figura 1?

Comment: Artur, um dia depois da tua pergunta saiu esse post: https://www.data-imaginist.com/2019/the-ggforce-awakens-again/

Comment: aahh muito interessante

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O pacote `ggforce` pode lhe ajudar nessa missão.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggforce)

tidy_landuse <- landuse$links %>% 
  gather_set_data(1:3)

ggplot(tidy_landuse, aes(x, id = id, split = y, value = value)) +
  geom_parallel_sets(alpha = 0.3, axis.width = 0.1) +
  geom_parallel_sets_axes(axis.width = 0.1) +
  geom_parallel_sets_labels(colour = 'white') +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("source", "target"), expand = c(0.05, 0.15))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tive que fazer uma pequena gambiarra para os gráfico sair como você precisava. Por algum motivo quando o `tidy_landuse` era gerado com `gather_set_data(1:2)`, que seria correto, o gráfico não saia. Então mudei para `1:3` e depois escondi o terceiro conjunto de barras paralelas com o `scale_x_discrete(limits = c("source", "target"))`.

Mais informações sobre o pacote podem ser encontradas em sua documentação e [nesta postagem](https://www.data-imaginist.com/2019/the-ggforce-awakens-again/).

Comment: Muito obrigado! Exatamente como queria. Tenho que melhorar a estética, colocar uma cor para cada classe e o nome da classe no lugar do ID. Vc acha que consigo mudar a cor com o `scale_fill_manual`?

Comment: Sim. Tente trocar a segunda linha do gráfico por `  geom_parallel_sets(aes(fill = factor(source)), alpha = 0.3, axis.width = 0.1) +` e veja o que acontece. É só uma opção para ver como funciona colocar o `fill` como estética mapeada.

Comment: na verdade quis dizer a cor das barras pretas. É possível mudar?

Comment: Consegue sim, no `geom_parallel_sets_axes` com as estéticas `fill` (cor de preenchimento) e `col` (cor do contorno).